# How to get the nearest closing tag

Tags: html, regex

I have a string like:

```
<tr><td>abc</td><td style="any" class="marked">dfg</td><td>hij</td></tr>
```

and I try to get marked td tag by such a regexp:

```
/<td.*class="marked.*<\/td>/si
```

but getting this:

```
<td>abc</td><td style="any" class="marked">dfg</td><td>hij</td>
```

How should I change my regexp to get such a string?

```
<td style="any" class="marked">dfg</td>
```

Comment: You should see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1864610)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Your expression doesn't guarantee that `class="marked"` is associated with the same tag as the `<td` at the start of the expression.
2. The `.*<\/td>` at the end is greedy and will match all the way to the last closing `</td>`.

This pattern will address both these issues:

```
/<td[^>]+class="marked">.*?<\/td>/si
```

Comment: As mentioned by @h2ooooooo in his answer, parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea.  It's only acceptable when you can make certain guarantees about the markup.  For example, this pattern will fail with `class="foo marked"`, or for a host of other reasons if the HTML isn't very similar to what was in your example.

Comment: jmar777: yes, I know that regexp not very good for html tasks. Thanks for the  answer

Answer (score 1):

`.*` is greedy and will match as much as possible.

`.*?` is lazy and will match as little as possible.

**tl;dr:** use `.*?` instead.

That said, regex is not an HTML parser, but [we've been through this many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)